# How to access a value outside a for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, save

I'm trying to access the new value of a variable outside a for loop.

This is for a system where users get a point everytime they move a card to the right index (everything is stored in indexedDB). I've already tried to make a global variable, but it goes back to 0 the second I move it outside the loop. When I access it inside the loop I can see the new value. I need the new value for a new function that will store the different values in a descending order (bascially making a leaderboard). 
How the code is now:

```js
let danielCounter = 0;

for (let i = 1; i < doneTasks.result+1; i++) {
    let getTasks = tasksStore.get(i);

    getTasks.onerror = function() {

    }

    getTasks.onsuccess = function() {
        if (getTasks.result.memberFullName == "Daniel") {
            danielCounter++;
        } else if (condition) {
            //something to be executed;
        }
    }
}

console.log("d: " + danielCounter);
```

I would expect the console.log to show "d: 5", because that is what it would show if the console.log was inside the for loop, but instead it's showing "d: 0" which is the value it starts with.

Comment: You are just setting the function onsuccess not calling it. So `danielCounter++;` is ne ver executed.

Comment: Looks like its never reaching the code where the `danielCounter` is incremented

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that, since `tasksStore.get(i)` is an *asynchronous* call, the `onsuccess` function is being called *after* the `console.log("d: " + danielCounter);` *synchronous* instruction is called. Try waiting a couple of seconds to print the variable value, or putting the `console.log` inside `onsuccess`.

Check out [this link](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/synchronous-asynchronous-javascript/) for more information about synchronous and asynchronous processes.

Answer (score 0):

The tasksStore.get(i) call is probably made asynchronously, so you will exit the loop before you have received all the results.

You could try awaiting the response in an async function, something like this

```
let danielCounter = 0;
```

`getDanielCount();

async function getDanielCount(){
    for (let i = 1; i < doneTasks.result+1; i++) {
        let getTasks = await tasksStore.get(i);

        getTasks.onerror = function() {

        }

        getTasks.onsuccess = function() {
            if (getTasks.result.memberFullName == "Daniel") {
                danielCounter++;
            } else if (condition) {
                //something to be executed;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("d: " + danielCounter);
}`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that may cause an issue.

Javascript is single threaded and has a concurrency model based on an "event loop".
So, the order in which your code is executed is as follows.

```
1. let danielCounter = 0;
2.
3. for (let i = 1; i < doneTasks.result+1; i++) {
4.    //taskStore.get is blocking method-- the method pushed into event event 
5.    // The control moves to next unblocked statement -- which is line 20!!
6.    let getTasks = tasksStore.get(i);
7.
8.    getTasks.onerror = function() {
9.
10.    }
11.
12.   getTasks.onsuccess = function() {
13.        if (getTasks.result.memberFullName == "Daniel") {
14.            danielCounter++;
15.        } else if (condition) {
16.            //something to be executed;
17.        }
18.    }
19.}

20. console.log("d: " + danielCounter);
```

Instead, try this code

```
async function  getDanielCount() {

    let danialCount = 0;

    for( i=0; i< tasksStore.length; i++) {
        let getTasks = await tasksStore.get(i);
        if (getTasks.result.memberFullName == "Daniel") {
            danielCounter++;
        } else if (condition) {
            //something to be executed;
        }

    }
    return danialCount;
}

(async () => { 
    let count = await getDanielCount();
    console.log('Daniel count', count); // This should display correct count
})();
```

The other thing I noticed is tasksStore.get(i) returns you an object 'getTasks' and your success and error functions are members of the newly created getTask object. Normally, you write a success and failure function separately and pass functions to the getTask method to receive a callback from getTask function.